# PostgreSQL - Multiple select primary key from three tables and insert as foreign key into one table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Edit: Apologize for blur and confused example, I'm going to edit the example to make the relations clearer.

I have a **COMPANY_RAWDATA** table as shown as follow:

```
 com_name  |  com_number | com_category | com_status 
-----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
Starbucks  | Star0121    | Drinks       | Active
KFC        | KFC1122     | Fast food    | Active
MCD        | MCD0000     | Fast food    | Active
MB         | MB2202      | Fast food    | Active
Chatime    | Pizza99     | Drinks       | Liquidation
```

The raw data are normalized into four tables which are:

(1) **COMPANY_DETAIL** with `com_detail_id` as PK

```
com_detail_id  | com_name  | com_number
---------------+-----------+------------
            1  | Starbucks | Star0121
            2  | KFC       | KFC1122
            3  | MCD       | MCD0000
            4  | MB        | MB2202
            5  | Chatime   | Pizza99
```

(2) **COMPANY_CATEGORY** table with `com_category_id` as PK

```
 com_category_id | com_category 
-----------------+--------------
               1 | Fast food    
               2 | Drinks       
               3 | Restaurant
```

(3) **COMPANY_STATUS** table with `com_status_id` as PK

```
 com_status_id |    com_status   
---------------+-------------------
             1 | Active                    
             2 | Liquidation        
             3 | In Administration
```

(4) **COMPANY** table with `com_id` as PK and other column possess FK constraints, they have relationship with each other.

```
com_id  |  com_detail_id | com_category_id | com_status_id 
--------+----------------+-----------------+---------------
```

All the primary key mentioned from (1) to (4) are declared with SERIAL.

The expected output should be:

```
   com_id  |  com_detail_id | com_category_id | com_status_id 
-----------+----------------+-----------------+---------------
        1  |              1 |               2 |             1
        2  |              2 |               1 |             1
        3  |              3 |               1 |             1
        4  |              4 |               1 |             1
        5  |              5 |               2 |             2
```

The three query to insert into specific columns written into a script are shown as below:

```
INSERT INTO company_rawdata (com_detail_id)
SELECT com_detail_id FROM company_detail AS detail, 
                          company_rawdata AS raw
WHERE detail.com_name   = rawdata.com_name
AND   detail.com_number = rawdata.com_number;

INSERT INTO company_rawdata (com_category_id)
SELECT com_category_id FROM company_category AS cat, 
                            company_rawdata AS raw
WHERE cat.com_category  = rawdata.com_category;

INSERT INTO company_rawdata (com_status_id)
SELECT com_status_id FROM company_status AS status, 
                          company_rawdata AS raw
WHERE status.com_status = rawdata.com_status;
```

I'm trying write a query to combine three *insert with select* query to insert these primary key from three different tables that match values with raw data and insert into company table.

Appreciate if you guys could provide a helping hand solve my question. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Do you want all possible combinations of all primary keys (cross join) or are the primary keys in the tables 1-3 somehow related?

Comment: They are related because these tables are actually normalized.

Comment: then please post all the relations - your example is enough only for cartesian product

Comment: The example is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your updatedd details I assume you are looking for:

```
INSERT INTO company (com_detail_id, com_category_id, com_status_id)
SELECT com_detail_id, com_category_id, com_status_id
FROM company_rawdata 
JOIN company_detail ON detail.com_name = rawdata.com_name AND detail.com_number = rawdata.com_number
JOIN company_category ON cat.com_category = rawdata.com_category
JOIN company_status  ON status.com_status = rawdata.com_status
;
```